# Flutter/Dart: Remove Elements from List based on index or mask

Tags: flutter, dart, filter, mapping

let's assume I have two lists `values` and `mask`:

```dart
List<int> values = [2,8,3,5,1];
List<bool> mask = [true, false, true, true, false];
// desired outcome: [2,3,5]
```

What is the shortest/best/most elegant way to filter the values based on the value of the mask?
For example in JavaScript I could do:

```js
values.filter((_, i) => mask[i]);
// yields: [2,3,5]
```

Is there something similar in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use asMap to solve this, the key is then the index and the value the original value.

````dart
values.asMap().entries.where((e) => mask[e.key]).map((e) => e.value).toList(); ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I figured this will work. If someone has another idea, I would be thankful :)

```dart
List.generate(values.length, (i) => i).where((i) => mask[i]).map((i) => values[i]).toList();
```